# Can't get PHP script to run when launched from Aptana Studio

Tags: php, aptana, execution

I've been using notepad++ for web development (currently html, css, and some php and mysql). I decided to dive into an IDE to see if I could cut down on development time and have more power than notepad++.

I grabbed Aptana yesterday and, after harassing it for a few hours, have finally gotten everything up and running. The only problem is that my web pages, which are .php's, do not execute any of their included php code in the browser.

as an example:

```
<?php
echo "IT WORKS WOOO";
?>
```

ought to print IT WORKS WOOO smack in the middle of my blank test page, and yet it does not. I checked to see if I had somehow forgotten how to do an echo statement and ran it on my desktop, using notepad++, and it worked just fine.

I have the php plugin, have used the php perspective to write it and have launched it as a php web page, but nothing makes it execute the php within.

Any ideas?

-Sqm

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: This is not a programming question, it's a software use/configuration question. Try http://superuser.com.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to this jam. moved it over.

Comment: @Dan: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it your using plug-ins to parse php files, which Aptana doesn't. You will need to install a php stack to test your scripts properly.

Try [Zend Server community edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/), which a full lamp stack.